# Error: "Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to load a program that does not exist" when change program id

Tags: solana-program, transactions, phantom, phantom-wallet

I learned about solana not long ago. I cloned [deep-links-movie-tutorial](https://github.com/phantom-labs/deep-links-movie-tutorial) and changed the program id to serve my project. However when I submit I get a message that cannot be simulated.

[image: Unable to simulate]

When I keep pressing **Approve** I get the error message on terminal: **Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to load a program that does not exist**

Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you are switched to the same cluster where the program is deployed.

Comment: @SwaroopMaddu Hi. I am noob. How to do that? Thx!!

Comment: In phantom open -> Developer Settings -> Change Network -> Select your network.

Comment: @SwaroopMaddu I have done that but still no success

Comment: Make sure the program is successfully deployed.

Comment: @SwaroopMaddu I don't have the .so file nor the rust anchor program, I just have that repo. I don't know how to deploy it.

Comment: Here it is https://github.com/Unboxed-Software/solana-movie-program